# QuickBlox Chat not logging in

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, chat, quickblox

I'm working on swift and quickblox and I'm trying to have chatting occur between users.
The user authentication and sign in is working its just that the chat isn't Logging in for some reason
Code in question:

```
                QBRequest.createSessionWithExtendedParameters(parameters, successBlock: { (response : QBResponse! ,session : QBASession!) -> Void in

                var currentUser = QBUUser()
                currentUser.ID = session.userID
                currentUser.password = userPassword as String
                QBChat().addDelegate(self)
                QBChat().loginWithUser(currentUser)



                let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
                appDelegate.initiateLocationServicesUpdates()

                self.boxView.removeFromSuperview()

                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("alreadySignedInSegue", sender: self)


                }, errorBlock: { (response : QBResponse!) -> Void in
                    self.boxView.removeFromSuperview()
                    NSLog("error: %@", response.error);
                    self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true
                    var alert : UIAlertController = UIAlertController()
                    let action : UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil)
                    if let error = response.error.reasons{
                        if  response.error.reasons.description.rangeOfString("Unauthorized") != nil{
                            alert = UIAlertController(title: "Oops", message: "Wrong Username/Password Combination", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                            alert.addAction(action)
                            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        alert = UIAlertController(title: "Oops", message: "Something Went Wrong, Its Our Fault!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                        alert.addAction(action)
                        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
            })
```

the segue found in the success block works but the value of
    QBChat().isLoggedIn()
is always false and if I try to send a message to a user id via the

```
QBChat().sendMessage(message: QBChatMessage!)
```

function I end up getting a "Must me logged in to chat to be able to send" message
. It must be a small problem that's due to me overlooking something.

`edit:` just so you know this is my first time working with quickblox, so please be precise about what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a shared instance of QBChat for working with chat.

```
QBChat.instance().addDelegate(self)
QBChat.instance().loginWithUser(currentUser)
```

Also check

```
setAutoCreateSessionEnabled
```

method in QBConnection. You can forget about session management.

Answer (score 0):

Please check my code working on Objective-C language.

For more info kindly [check](http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios)

```
// Login to QuickBlox Chat
[[ChatService instance] loginWithUser:[LocalStorageService shared].currentUser completionBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"------------local sotrage Logged In user=%@", [LocalStorageService shared].currentUser);
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"You have successfully logged in"
                                                                message:nil
                                                               delegate:nil
                                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                      otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
    //
    // hide alert after delay
    double delayInSeconds = 2.0;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
    });



    [[UserChoice sharedUserChoice]setIsConnectedUser:1];
    MySlideViewController *slideViewController = [[MySlideViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SlideViewController" bundle:nil];
    slideViewController.myDataUser = resultG;
    slideViewController.delegate = slideViewController;
    [[UserChoice sharedUserChoice] setMyUserProfile:resultG];
    slideViewController.myDataUserIn = [[UserChoice sharedUserChoice]myUserProfile];
    slideViewController.paramGeolocalisation = paramGeo;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:slideViewController animated:YES];
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

}];
```

or Do this

```
// login to Chat
[[QBChat instance] loginWithUser:currentUser];

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark QBChatDelegate

// Chat delegate
-(void) chatDidLogin{
    // You have successfully signed in to QuickBlox Chat

    // Now you can send a message

}
```

Comment: I'm using the second method. The chatDidLogin function is not running. The delegate is set to the current controller its a QBChatDelegate

Comment: try with creating a new user

Comment: **currentUser** instance is empty, you should set **ID** and **password** at least to login to Chat

For example

    QBUUser *user = [QBUUser user];
    user.ID = 1212122;
    user.password = @"userpassword";
    [[QBChat instance] loginWithUser:user];

Sorry no knowledge of swift :(

Comment: tried creating a new user, didn't work. I tried to just create the user statically in the code it also didn't work. The code i have is basically translated from the link you gave me. It must be a problem related to swift maybe. I was never able to find a quickblox chat project to use as a reference